# Combining the jQuery onbeforeunload event with jQuery UI Modal Message

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, onbeforeunload

I'm having trouble combining the jQuery `onbeforeunload` event with the jQuery UI Modal Message.  I'd like to use the jquery onbeforeunload event to check if a form has been submitted yet or not, and if it hasn't been submitted the user is asked if they want to save their changes.

The 1rst function provides a system prompt and works properly, but it's difficult to customize the style or button text and requires several clicks from the user.

The 2nd function uses the jQuery UI Dialog Widget, but it's currently triggering the function which shows the dialog when any field is changed as opposed to when the user tries to leave the page. How can I correct this function so that it's triggered when a user clicks to leave the page without submitting the form?

I'm using jquery-1.8.2 and jquery-ui-1.9.1

```
<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="form2-exec.php">        
    <!-- Form Elements -->
    <div id="dialog-confirm" style="display:none;">
        Would you like to save your changes?
    </div>
    <a href="form1.php">BACK</a>
    <a href="#"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></a>
</form>
```

**Original Function**

```
$(function () {
    // Set the unload message whenever any form elements are changed
    $('input', 'select').change(function () {
        setConfirmUnload(true);
    });
    // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly.
    $('form').submit(function () {
        setConfirmUnload(false);
    });
});
function setConfirmUnload(on) {
    var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?";
    window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null;
}
```

**New setConfirmUnload(on) Function** *(Doesn't work correctly)*

```
function setConfirmUnload(on) {
  var message = $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                $("#form2").submit();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Continue": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });        
    window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function () { return message; } : null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try moving the definition of the dialog into the `window.onbeforeunload` handler like this:

```
function setConfirmUnload(on) { 
    var message;       
    if (on) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            message = $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $("#form2").submit();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Continue": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
             });
             return message;
        };
    } else {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's causing both the standard system prompt and the dialog to pop up :-(